# Wamp Server Apache Ports for use

Tags: apache, wamp

I tried ports `80`,`8080`, `8888`, `8000`, `8443`, but my apache still will not start? My question is which ports can I specify for Apache use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

always check for duplicate installed servers.